# Changing UUID for an LVM2_member

Tags: 18.04, ssd, clone, uuid

I have cloned my SSD and rebooted with a Live distro to change the corresponding UUID.

Unfortunately when I run

```
tune2fs -U {some_UUID} /dev/sda5
```

I get the error

```
tune2fs: Bad magic number ....
/dev/sda5 contains a LVM2_member
```

This happens for both copies.. so I cannot change the UUID. If I try to book, the system does not start because of the duplicated UUIDs.

How can I change the UUID in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix it running:

```
pvchange --uid /dev/sda5
```

Answer (score 0):

pvchange --uuid /dev/sda5

## or

pvchange -u /dev/sda5

see man page: [pvchange.man.txt](https://dwaves.org/man/pvchange.man.txt)

```
   -u|--uuid
          Generate new random UUID for specified PVs.
```